# ccls configuration in nvim-lspconfig

Tags: neovim

I've been struggling for setting [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) in Neovim.

I've ever used [clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/) for a long time; after following [TJ's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puWgHa7k3SY) and [instructions on nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#clangd), it works well.

Now I would like to switch to [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) and the configuration seems doesn't make it work.

1. I've installed [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) on the system.

   [image]
2. Neovim is aware of [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) while it is running `.c` files.
   [image]

Note: The operating system is Windows 10 rather than Ubuntu.

**But the problem is**, as shown in 2., there is no client (i.e., [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) that I expect) attached to the buffer.

It seems that there are more tutorials for setting [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) on [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) than on [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/tree/master). But I need the latter.

For now, my nvim-lspconfig configuration is as follows.

```
local capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities()
require('lspconfig').ccls.setup{
  capabilities = capabilities,
  on_attach = function()
                print("Hello! C/C++!")  -- To remind me that ccls is attached
                vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, {buffer = 0})
                vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, {buffer = 0})
                vim.keymap.set('n', 'gt', vim.lsp.buf.type_definition, {buffer = 0})
                vim.keymap.set('n', 'gi', vim.lsp.buf.implementation, {buffer = 0})
                vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>dj', vim.diagnostic.goto_next, {buffer = 0})
                vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>dk', vim.diagnostic.goto_prev, {buffer = 0})
                vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>dl', "<cmd>Telescope diagnostic<CR>", {buffer = 0})
                vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>r', vim.lsp.buf.rename, {buffer = 0}) 
              end,
}
```

In addition, the environment info

```
OS: Windows 10

Neovim version:
  NVIM v0.9.1
  Build type: RelWithDebInfo
  LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

Plugin manager: Packer
```

Is there something I missed? Could any one help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `.ccls` file in the file's directory. *ccls* looks for a `.ccls` file or a `compile_commands.json` file to identify the project root directory. I have just encountered the same problem, and making an empty `.ccls` file solved the problem for me.